# C Linked List: Access violation reading location 0x00000001

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list

I am very new to linked list and need a little help. Currently I am receiving this error"

> Unhandled exception at 0x0FD940C1 (msvcr120d.dll) in
>   ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0x00000001.

What the program is trying to do is take a file and iterating through it and creating a linked list, each node consisting of the string value and a node pointer to the next node. I have followed multiple tutorials and I am not sure what the issue is. If anybody could help, that would be fantastic.

Below is my code:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFF_SIZE 300

typedef struct node {
    char stringDat[BUFF_SIZE];
    struct node* next;
} NODE;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE* fp;
    FILE* fpLogFile;

    char* fileLoc = "C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\data.dat";
    char* logFile = "C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\log.txt";

    char buff[BUFF_SIZE]; 
    int i, nodeCnt;

    if ((fp = fopen(fileLoc, "rb+")) == NULL) {
        printf("FILE OPEN ERROR ON EXISTING FILE\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((fpLogFile = fopen(logFile, "w")) == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening log file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // root node
    NODE* root = NULL;

    // provide memory for root node
    root = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if (root == NULL){
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(fpLogFile, "%s\n", "ROOT MALLOC");
    nodeCnt = 1;

    // assign values to root node
    root->next = NULL;
    fprintf(fpLogFile, "%s\n", "ROOT Next = 0");

    strcpy(root->stringDat, fread(buff, 20, 1, fp));
    fprintf(fpLogFile, "%s\n", "ROOT buff");

    // set curr to root node
    NODE* curr = root;
    fprintf(fpLogFile, "%s\n", "Curr = ROOT");

    while (fread(buff, 20, 1, fp) != NULL) {

        // navigate to last node in list
        while (curr->next != NULL) {
            curr = curr->next;
        }

        fprintf(fpLogFile, "%s\n", "Curr = last node");

        // Create node at end of list
        curr->next = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        fprintf(fpLogFile, "%s\n", "Malloc new Node");
        nodeCnt++;
        // move current node to last node
        curr = curr->next;

        if (curr == 0) {
            fprintf(fpLogFile, "%s\n", "Out of memory");
            return 0;
        }
        // assign val to current stringDat
        strcpy(curr->stringDat, buff);

        fprintf(fpLogFile, "%s     %d    %p    %d\n", curr->stringDat, strlen(curr->stringDat), curr->next, nodeCnt);

        for (i = 0; i < BUFF_SIZE; i++) {
            buff[i] = 0;
        }


    }

    while ((curr = root) != NULL) { // set curr to head, stop if list empty.
        root = root->next;          // advance head to next element.
        free(curr);                // delete saved pointer.
    }

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fpLogFile);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What line does the error occur?

Comment: Not sure and it is not included in the error message, that's why I started putting in all the fprintf for debugging via a log file. But I do know that I was able to read the file fine, it's when I began adding all the nodes that things went crazy

Comment: Your debugger should tell you exactly where it happens...

Comment: run it under the vs debugger, it will break where the error occurrs

Comment: You are not setting the `next` of the new node to `NULL` after `// Create node at end of list`

Comment: It's breaking on the first strcpy (line 52 in my VS) @SamiKuhmonen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
strcpy(root->stringDat, fread(buff, 20, 1, fp));
```

makes no sense, and should have triggered a compiler warning.

The second argument to `strcpy()` is a string pointer, but `fread()` returns `size_t` (the number of "elements" it succeeded in reading). When it succeeds here, it will return `1` which will trigger the error you're getting.

You meant:

```
if(fread(buff, 20, 1, fp) == 1)
  strcpy(root->stringDat, buff);
```

Comment: That makes sense and is the answer, thanks a ton for the help! One more thing, around line 76, I am malloc'ing a new node instance, but I am hitting by "Out of memory" error checker. I allocated the mem, then move to the new node, but it is saying my new node == 0....any ideas?

Comment: @Dpry12 See Eugene Sh.'s comment on your question.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yup, it was that and the fact that I was moving to the next node before assigning values to the current node I was on! thanks for the help